# POST request from android to PHP

Tags: php, android, cakephp, http-post, mojibake

I want to send a POST request from android to a PHP application in utf-8 with the below code:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Site.SQL_QUERY, "just a test 東京"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
urlEncodedFormEntity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
httppost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), HTTP.UTF_8));
String result = reader.readLine();
```

I set encoding to UTF-8, but Japanese characters contained in the string are not displayed normally.

Here is my PHP code(cakePHP). I just dump parameter.

```
function sqlQuery(){
   var_dump($this->params['form']['sql_query']);exit;
}
```

It will display something like "just a test □□"

I have also tried with

```
mb_convert_encoding ($this->params['form']['sql_query'],"UTF-8")
```

But problem persists...

Someone can help me ?
Thank you

Comment: I found the solution !           UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
         urlEncodedFormEntity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
         httppost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

Comment: what cakephp version are you using? in 2.x its `$this->request->data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been the problem Sending UTF-8 data from Android. Your code would work fine except that you will have to encode your `String` to    `Base64` . At Server PHP you just decode `Base64` String back. It worked for me. I can share if you need the code.

Comment: I have encoded my parameters in Base64 and now it works ~ thank you